# Use Auto Fit with Tags for Gmap3?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

Im trying to combine the 2 features for Gmap3 below (although the Auto Fit demo in the link appears not to work, when I add the parameter to my local demo it works fine):

http://gmap3.net/examples/tags.html

http://gmap3.net/api/auto-fit.html

So I want to have tickboxes for regions that make markers visible and invisible, and I want the map to automatically zoom in and out after this selection to show all the pins on the page.

Is this possible and how do I go about achieving this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the autofit doesn't take care of removed items.

But you may implement this on your own.

For the given example this modifications will do it:

---

## 1.

replace  this line:

```
tmp[ ville.region ] = true;
```

by:

```
if( tmp[ ville.region ])
{
 tmp[ ville.region ].bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(ville.lat,ville.lng))
}
else
{
 tmp[ ville.region ]=
  {
   bounds:new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(ville.lat,ville.lng)),
   checked:true
  }
}
```

It will store for each region the LatLngBounds and the status(checked)

---

## 2.

Add right after this:

```
 $.each(markers, function(i, marker){
                marker.setMap( checked ? map : null);
            });
```

these lines:

```
tmp[region].checked=checked;
var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

$.each(tmp,function(i,o)
                      {
                        if(o.checked)
                        {
                          bounds.union(o.bounds);
                        }
                      }
                  );
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

it will set the checked-status of the current region and then calulate the LatLngBounds for all visible regions. The result will be used as argument for map.fitBounds()

---

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nBtVB/

Comment: To stop the default zoom on page load comment out these lines: // center:[46.578498,2.457275],
// zoom: 5